# Maximum notation

Tags: functional-analysis

Suppose I have the following expression
$$\max_{x \in X} |f(x) - g(x)|$$

I have always understood this to be "select **one** $x \in X$ for which the quantity attains its maximum value." But recently someone has given me reason to think we may select different inputs for each function $f$ and $g$.

If the latter is true, then is the interchange of the absolute value with $\max$ true? That is, does $\max$ have linearity so that we can rewrite the above as:

$$|\max_{x \in X}[f(x)] - \max_{x \in X}[g(x)]|$$?

Comment: Your original understanding is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The argument to $\max$ is a single function, which happens to be the difference between the functions $f$ and $g$. That single function has a single argument $x$, and therefore there is no way you could choose a different argument for $f$ and $g$.

If you want to say that the arguments of $f$ and $g$ are to be independently chosen, then you can write $\max_{x,y\in X}\left|f(x) - g(y)\right|$. Note however that in general that expression will also not be the same as $\left|\max[f(x)] - \max[g(x)]\right|$ because you cannot move the absolute value bars out of the maximum function; for example, $\max_{x\in\mathbb R}\left|\sin(x)-1\right| = 2$, but $\left|\max_{x\in\mathbb R}[\sin(x)-1]\right| = 0$.